# How to construct a tuple with four elements from two pairs with matching data types in C++?

Tags: c++, std-pair, stdtuple

I have a function `f()`, that returns a `std::pair<A, B>` with some types `A` and `B`. And I have another function `g()`, that calls `f()` twice and returns a `std::tuple<A, B, A, B>`. Is there a way to construct the return `tuple` directly from both calls to `f()`? So I would like to shortcut the last three lines of my current code:

```
std::tuple<A, B, A, B>
g(type1 arg1, type2 arg2, ...) {
    // perform some preprocessing
    auto pair1 = f(...);
    auto pair2 = f(...);
    return { pair1.first, pair1.second, pair2.first, pair2.second }
}
```

into a one liner (instead of three). It would be nice, if that solution also worked with tuples of arbitrary length, especially in a template situation.

For example, in current Python3, the solution would be `return (*f(...), *f(...))`. Is there a similiar list/tuple unwrap operator in C++ as there is in Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is [`std::tuple_cat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat). Even though cppreference says that...

> The behavior is undefined if any type in [arguments] is not a specialization of `std::tuple`. However, an implementation may choose to support types (such as `std::array` and `std::pair`) that follow the tuple-like protocol.

I've tested it and all major standard library implementations (libstdc++, libc++, and MSVC's library) do support it.

Example:

```
#include <tuple>

struct A {};
struct B {};

std::pair<A, B> foo() {return {};}

std::tuple<A, B, A, B> bar()
{
    return std::tuple_cat(foo(), foo());
}
```

Comment: the relevant note: https://eel.is/c++draft/tuple.creation#12

Comment: and I was curious, so I looked up documentation of libstdc++, it requires `__is_tuple_like<_Tpls>`, but thats about as far as I was willing to dig ;) https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/libstdc++/api/a01483.html#ga23a2e3e40fefd39ffe278df7ebbd52a0

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I guess those are the standard tuple requirements, similar to the ones used for structured bindings and the like.